# show git diff and git status simultaneously

Tags: git, shell, unix, sh, zsh

I'd like a way to get a pager-view (`less`) of a buffer of git diff and git status to get a nice complete summary of the state of my working changes. It helps because `git diff` alone will hide the staged changes whereas `status` will be able to highlight that.

I know I can probably do something like

```
{ git status && git diff | cat }
```

which basically concats the output here, but this causes `git diff` to drop the syntax colors.

I could probably use `perl` but I'd like to use some neat `sh`, `bash` or `zsh` trick to concat this stuff while keeping colors intact.

Also, my git diff uses

```
[pager]
    log = diff-highlight | less
    show = diff-highlight | less
    diff = diff-highlight | less
```

So perhaps i gotta set something custom up where it skips the use of `less` so I can apply my `less` over the concatenated output.

Comment: `git diff --color | cat` doesn't drop colors, just FYI. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just explicitly compare against what's already been committed:

```
git diff HEAD
```

That will show you the complete diff, regardless of what's been staged or not. If you *do* want to see what's been staged and what hasn't, then you can just explicitly request color before concatenating:

```
git status && git diff --color | cat
```

Note that this still drops the color from the `git status` command. If you want that colored as well, you can take advantage of Git's ability to override configuration values on a per-command basis:

```
git -c color.ui=always status && git diff --color | cat
```

Comment: cool. I actually like to have the ability to whittle down the unstaged changes and view a summary (which status provides nicely), so it's basically appending the status to the diff as they are by default. I had just wanted the colors to stay.